# SCSS display text on hovering score

Tags: sass, hover, display

I'm trying to display different text boxes on hover, could you please help me to understand why it is not working?
I'll link the fiddle in a comment.

Comment: *https://codepen.io/rebekaranna/pen/gOrXzdp*

Comment: The `+` symbol only matches an element that *immediately* follows the one before it. Take `.score-1b:hover + .test-text-1b`, for example. This would require that the `.test-text-1b` element directly follows `.score-1b` in your HTML--but it doesn't. You'll need to restructure your HTML. Also do some reading on the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) (`~`).

Comment: Thank you! I can't restructure it in a way that those divs become siblings. I will have to go for Javascript then.